# Real analysis: Show the limit $\lim nμ(E_n) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, R, μ)$ be a measurable space. Let $f$ be a measurable and integrable function on $X$. Let $E_n = \{x ∈ X|f(x) > n\}$. Prove that $\lim nμ(E_n) = 0$.

I know that $\mu(E_n)$ is equal to its outer measure, and it goes to $0$. But I do not know how show that and show $n\mu(E_n)$ goes to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
n\mu(E_n) \leq \int_{E_n} fd\mu \leq \int_{E_n}|f|d\mu
$$
Since $f\in L^1$, for every $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that
$$
\mu(A) < \delta \Rightarrow \int_A |f|d\mu < \epsilon
$$
Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\mu(E_n) < \delta \quad\forall n\geq N
$$
Then
$$
n\mu(E_n) < \epsilon \quad\forall n\geq N
$$

Comment: What is your definition of $f\in L^1$? The definition that I have states that if $f\in L^1$ then $\int_X|f|<\infty$. I am not sure If my definition can help to arrive to the desired result. Can it?

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim \;n\mu(E_n) = \lim \int_{\{x:|f(x)|>n\}} n \;d\mu \leq \lim \int_{\{x:|f(x)|>n\}} |f| \;d\mu = \int_{\{x:|f(x)|=\infty\}} |f| \;d\mu=0$$ That last equality follows because $f \in L^1$ implies that $|f|<\infty$ a.e, and the second-to-last equality follows because $\{x:|f(x)|=\infty\} = \bigcap_n \{x:|f(x)|>n\}$ is the intersection from a family of decreasing sets.

Comment: Can you explain with more details why $\int_{\{x:|f(x)|=\infty\}}|f|d\mu=0$ ? I don't understand